# Error message - Creating a new Key store (PKCS12) (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

I would like to publish my app on the Play Store. Therefore at first I need  to create a signed APK. Everytime I would like to create a new Keystore two error messages appear (see below).

First one:

> Warning: No support for different storage and key passwords for PKCS12
> KeyStores. The user-defined value -keypass is ignored.

By clicking on "OK", another error message appear (see screenshot)

Second one:

[image]

I fulfilled all the necessary input fields for the keystore as in the developer description from Android mentioned (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

PS: I'm using the latest Android Studio version

Please, I hope someone knows a solution for this problem because Google/I couldn't find a solution yet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Solved!!!!: To work around this issue, enter the same password for both the key and keystore!! https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?skip_cache=true&hl=ar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!!: To work around this issue, enter the **same** password for **both the key and keystore**!! developer.android.com/studio/releases?skip_cache=true&hl=ar

Answer (score 0):

Just enter again the username and password, it will work. Is a common msg error in Android studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).